# Certificate Verify Fail while installing anything with pip

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I have been getting this error

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PJIE.png)

I first got this error when I tried to fetch a page in python requests module, everything used to work fine but now it does not. Whenever I try to fetch the page it throws

> certificate verify failed | bad handshake

I followed up some posts on stack recommending to reinstall certifi, I did uninstall that but now I cannot install it back.

Error while fetching a page with requests

[requests error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAdIO.png)

Comment: have you tried it with a simple package like pip install numpy ? And have you tried it in a command line which was started with admin priviliges?

Comment: Yes I tried with django and other packages that were install successfully in the past, and yes I am doing this with admin priviliges.

Comment: Please include the full error message as text instead of as a screenshot image.

Comment: Added the error for requests, however i am not sure what you mean by full error message, if it is for the pip that is the full msg.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing my python installation fixed the issue for me.